# I have multiple IDs for items, how can I use VLOOKUP to scan next column if it doesnt find it in the first?

Tags: excel, vlookup

Imagine my dataset has multiple IDs in columns, for the same item. How can I use VLOOKUP to scan the next column in the order up until it finds the same ID in another dataset? Or if it does not exist just stop searching after 6 columns? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with 6 nested IFERROR statements; that would look like this: (Assuming your ID columns are A->F, your results column is G, and your search term is in J1):

```
=IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(J1,A:G,7,0),VLOOKUP(J1,B:G,6,0)),VLOOKUP(J1,C:G,5,0)),VLOOKUP(J1,D:G,4,0)),VLOOKUP(J1,E:G,3,0)),VLOOKUP(J1,F:G,2,0))
```

This looks at each column (starting with F and working outwards), and if it can't find a match, it creates an error, so goes to the next column. It is not very clean to read. A better way using this same methodology could be to use a combination of INDEX & MATCH, like so:

```
=INDEX(G:G,IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(MATCH(J1,A:A,0),MATCH(J1,B:B,0)),MATCH(J1,C:C,0)),MATCH(J1,D:D,0)),MATCH(J1,E:E,0)),MATCH(J1,F:F,0))
```

Though this is a little shorter [because we don't need to specify the entire block of data, or which column to pull from, as it always pulls from column G], it is still not very readable.

Let's try this instead using an Array Formula which runs the same function multiple times over many cells, gets the result for each cell, and provides an array of results. Then we just need to collapse that array into a single value, like so:

```
=INDEX(G1:G14,MIN(IFERROR(IF(SEARCH(J1,A1:A14&B1:B14&C1:C14&D1:D14&E1:E14&F1:F14)>0,ROW(A1:A14),""),"")))
```

Confirm this formula with CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER instead of just ENTER. This adds all strings of all search columns together, basically making a single column of values. It then takes that column, and searches each cell for the word found in J1. If it finds it, it returns that row number, otherwise it returns "". The function then uses MIN to take the lowest row number found (to tie-break to the earliest row, if there is a duplicate), and then uses that with INDEX to return the value from that row in column G.

Note that the logic here is a little different from the options I gave above, as it defaults to the earliest row #, rather than the earliest column #, of a match.